# how to draw line one after the other in css

Tags: html, css

I want to draw a line before and after the text. And I want to do  these features twice. Like in the image below :  How can I achieve this? I tried before and after but could not solve it. I am beginner in CSS. THanks for your time.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @0stone0 how is it a bad question? They don't know how to make a double parallel line on either side of a heading. Are you just wanting him to add some code to show what they've tried so far?

Comment: @Sensoray, If you read the linked posts, there are quite some point missing in the question. The reason I downvoted is: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/. Doesn't matter that OP doesn't know how to do it, but SO requires some attempts to be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, with `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.

```css
.team {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  color: darkslategray;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.team-span {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.team-span::before,
.team-span::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 0.2em;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  /* the lines */
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="team">
  <span class="team-span">Our Best Team</span> Our Team
</h2>
```

Comment: thanks for your respond. Is there a way to decrease the width of the second line?

Comment: I'm not sure if you could do that without changing the markup. Usually, I would use a pseudo element to do that, but a pseudo element can't have another pseudo element of itself.